# Best way for key comparison (C++ map)

Tags: c++, dictionary, comparison

While working with maps I am sometimes having some problems while defining the comparison function for the insertion into the maps with my own data types. For example, at the moment I have a structure like this:

```
typedef struct triple_key{
    int int_key;
    struct some_data;
    unsigned char char_array_key[16];
}triple_key;
```

where some_data is like this:

```
struct some_data{
    int data_length;
    unsigned char* data;
}
```

For the comparison I am overwriting the operator(), and my idea is to do the following:

```
class comp_triple_key{
public:
bool operator()(const triple_key &x, const triple_key &y){
    if(x.int_key!= y.int_key){
        return x.int_key<y.int_key;
    }
    else{
       if(memcmp((x.some_data).data, (y.some_data).data, (x.some_data).data_length) != 0){
          return memcmp((x.some_data).data, (y.some_data).data, (x.some_data).data_length) < 0;
       }
       else{
           return memcmp((x.char_array_key), (y.char_array_key), 16*sizeof(char))<0;
       }
   }
};
```

};

Then the map will be as follows:

```
 std::map<triple_key,int,comp_triple_key> my_map;
```

Is there a better way to compare this multiple key values? In most of cases this works (and works fine), but sometimes I get the assertion:

```
Expression: invalid operator <
```

I have handled this problem in the past, but I have not clear how to avoid it in general or which are the common ways to work with something like this to ensure that it works for every case.

Comment: Are you sure your example compiles? You can't pass `std::array` to `memcmp`.

Comment: You need to take care of the case where the `data_length`s are different - they may compare differently (and invoke undefined behaviour) depending on the argument order.

Comment: @jrok Totally right, it was my mistake. I have edited and now is the real example :)

Comment: @molbdnilo exactly that is what I think. Maybe the memcmp only with the length of the shortest? what about having a key with length = 0?

Comment: Why not just implement `<` for the key type?

Comment: Those `memcmp` calls should probably be wrapped in a class that encapsulates such comparison.

Comment: @estradjs It would be simplest if you could ignore it and only identify things by the other members. Otherwise, I would say it depends on the nature of the data.

Comment: What is this `struct some_data;`? And why `uuid` is not compared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler the better. Just compare one by one with this scheme:

```
bool operator()(const triple_key &x, const triple_key &y){
   if (x.int_key < y.int_key)  
     return true;
   if (y.int_key < x.int_key)
     return false;
   if (lexicographical_compare(x.some_data.data, x.some_data.data + x.some_data.data_length,
                               y.some_data.data, y.some_data.data + y.some_data.data_length))
      return true;
   if (lexicographical_compare(y.some_data.data, y.some_data.data + y.some_data.data_length,
                               x.some_data.data, x.some_data.data + x.some_data.data_length))
      return false;
   return memcmp(x.char_array_key, y.char_array_key, sizeof(y.char_array_key)) < 0; 
}
```

Comment: This works perfect, I didn't know the lexicographical_compare, I think it makes it really simple, cool! ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are several things to do :

- instead defining comparator class (comp_triple_key in your case), define `operator<` for triple_key

Something like this works :

```
  bool operator<(const triple_key &x, const triple_key &y){
    if(x.int_key!= y.int_key){
        return x.int_key<y.int_key;
    }
    else{
       if(memcmp((x.somedata).data, (y.somedata).data, (x.somedata).data_length) != 0){
          return memcmp((x.somedata).data, (y.somedata).data, (x.somedata).data_length) < 0;
       }
       else{
           return memcmp((x.char_array_key), (y.char_array_key), 16*sizeof(char))<0;
       }
    }
  }
```

then you can create objects like :

```
std::map<triple_key,int> my_map;
```

---

Compilable example (fixed code in the question) :

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>


struct some_data{
    int data_length;
    unsigned char* data;
};

struct triple_key{
    int int_key;
    some_data somedata ;
    unsigned char char_array_key[16];
};

  bool operator<(const some_data &x, const some_data &y){
    if(x.int_key!= y.int_key){
        return x.int_key<y.int_key;
    }
    else{
       if(memcmp((x.somedata).data, (y.somedata).data, (x.somedata).data_length) != 0){
          return memcmp((x.somedata).data, (y.somedata).data, (x.somedata).data_length) < 0;
       }
       else{
           return memcmp((x.char_array_key), (y.char_array_key), 16*sizeof(char))<0;
       }
    }
  }

  bool operator<(const triple_key &x, const triple_key &y){
    if(x.int_key!= y.int_key){
        return x.int_key<y.int_key;
    }
    else{
       if(memcmp((x.somedata).data, (y.somedata).data, (x.somedata).data_length) != 0){
          return memcmp((x.somedata).data, (y.somedata).data, (x.somedata).data_length) < 0;
       }
       else{
           return memcmp((x.char_array_key), (y.char_array_key), 16*sizeof(char))<0;
       }
    }
  }

int main()
{
    std::map<triple_key,int> my_map;
}
```

Comment: @estradjs What do you mean? This operator is a function, and I just copy&paster your code. I had to fix some thing which prevented the code from compiling.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
struct some_data{
    int data_length;
    unsigned char* data;

    bool operator < (const some_data& other) const
    {
        if (memcpy(data, other.data, data_length)  < 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};

typedef struct triple_key{
    int int_key;
    struct some_data data;
    unsigned char uuid[16];

    bool operator < (const triple_key& other) const
    {
        if (int_key < other.int_key)
            return true;
        else
        {
            if (data < other.data)
                return true;
            else
            {
                if (memcpy((void*)uuid, (void*)other.uuid, sizeof(uuid)) < 0)
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}triple_key;

int main()
{
    some_data data1;
    data1.data = (unsigned char *)malloc(4);
    data1.data_length = 4;

    some_data data2;
    data2.data = (unsigned char *)malloc(5);
    data2.data_length = sizeof(5);

    triple_key key1;
    key1.int_key = 1;
    key1.data = data1;

    triple_key key2;
    key2.int_key = 2;
    key2.data = data2;

    std::map<triple_key, int> myMap;
    myMap[key1] = 1;
    myMap[key2] = 2;

    cout<<myMap.size()<<endl;
}
```